# Disable Hyperthreading online

Tags: cpu, multicore, hyperthreading

I have an Ubuntu server which has the following attributes ( snapshot)

processor       : 23
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 44
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5690  @ 3.47GHz
stepping        : 2
cpu MHz         : 1600.000
cache size      : 12288 KB
physical id     : 1
siblings        : 12
core id         : 10
cpu cores       : 6

For the system under test, hyper threading is enabled. I want to disable the hyper threading for this system. I don't want to boot up and go to BIOS to do so but want to get it done online. Several suggestions I came across were to do something like below:

'echo 0 >/sys/devices/system/node/node0/cpu2/online'

I am not sure which CPU or node shall I go to and perform the following operation based on the numbers of CPU cores, siblings in the system.

Any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
I am not sure which CPU or node shall I go to and perform the following operation 
based on the numbers of CPU cores, siblings in the system.
```

Parallel benchmarking the system would assess performance and maximum throughput of a multi core CPU's, which can tell us enabling/disabling of hyper threading for the system.